# Determine if a CSS class exists with Javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Is there a way to determine whether or not a CSS class exists using JavaScript?

Comment: What do you mean by a class exists? That there is at least one element with that class or that there is at least one CSS rule that is applied on elements with that class?

Comment: Sorry, I mean... Does the class definition exist in the browser's memory?  In other words, has the class been defined internally or in a loaded stylesheet?

Comment: hey I know it's an old question but did you find a code to solve this?I 've been trying for hours with no luck.Thanks

Comment: I believe I ended up writing something myself using the accepted answer. It's been a long time though. I haven't had access to that code base in years. Sorry.

Comment: Solutions that loops stylesheets don't work well in Chrome and Firefox, which have same-origin check. The code is unable to read a stylesheet from another domain!

Comment: I know this is old but ideally, if it doesn't exist, there would an array or dictionary or map in the document where you could easily check and do something like `document.classes.indexOf("myClassName")!=-1` or `document.classes.has("myClassName")` or `'myClassName` in document.classes`

Comment: If you know about your class, what styles it changes (non-default styles), you could possibly create a new HTML element, get the style object, then add the class to the element and check the style object again. and check if there's changes (or check for references). If there are changes then the class exists. You could also check computedStyles.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This should be possible to do using the `document.styleSheets[].rules[].selectorText` and `document.styleSheets[].imports[].rules[].selectorText` properties. Refer to [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.styleSheets).

Comment: Use the google cache link to see the Expert Exchange answer or do the search for "JavaScript: Checking if a CSS class exists" in Google to go there. Expert exchange is a little anal about showing answers you either need a Google referrer or use the Google Cache (otherways may work, but these i know!)

http://209.85.229.132/search?q=cache:y8Pj_46Q6O0J:www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/Scripting/JavaScript/Q_21685655.html+JavaScript:+Checking+if+a+CSS+class+exists&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk

Comment: Thanks, I found that link earlier and tried looking at the google cache but apparently didn't scroll far enough down the page.  The first few responses all had the "register to view" text on them.

Comment: Code is listed on the link in Shadi's comment above.  Basically you troll through the selectors in memory looking for the selector text.  Thanks Helen  Thanks Shadi

Comment: @Shadi Almosri: Thanks for the tip! I've updated the link in the answer. Actually, with Opera I never have problems viewing answers on experts exchange. :) But Google cache or Archive.org links should be more accessible, I agree.

Comment: The experts-exchange secret is to just keep scrolling.  The answers are there below all their "sign up now!" text.

Comment: Answer is not on the page, even if you keep on scrolling >_>

Comment: @AshBlue: Looks like EE changed their website design. Try the archive.org version: http://web.archive.org/web/20071210160927/http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/Scripting/JavaScript/Q_21685655.html. Alternatively, you can view answers on the "live" site by spoofing your user agent string to look like Googlebot (e.g. using Firefox's User Agent Switcher extension).

Comment: IE and firefox only cssRules : document.styleSheets[].cssRules[]

Comment: firefox only cssRules : document.styleSheets[].cssRules[]

Answer (score 15):

```
function getAllSelectors() { 
    var ret = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < document.styleSheets.length; i++) {
        var rules = document.styleSheets[i].rules || document.styleSheets[i].cssRules;
        for(var x in rules) {
            if(typeof rules[x].selectorText == 'string') ret.push(rules[x].selectorText);
        }
    }
    return ret;
}


function selectorExists(selector) { 
    var selectors = getAllSelectors();
    for(var i = 0; i < selectors.length; i++) {
        if(selectors[i] == selector) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: doesn't work very well, at least on chrome.. 1. opened developer console (f12). 2. pasted the function getAllSelectors(). 3. called it right here on this page, all I got was: [".wmd-snippet-button span", ".wmd-snippet-button:hover span", "#newsletter-ad", "#newsletter-ad-header", "#newsletter-ad ul", "#newsletter-ad ul li", "#newsletter-signup-container", "#newsletter-preview-container", "#newsletter-email-input"]. <-- (this is obviously not all the selectors on this page)

Comment: Does not returns css rules from included stylesheets

Comment: Got: Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'rules' property from 'CSSStyleSheet': Cannot access rules

Comment: ⚠️ This is too verbose. Please remove and upvote one of the existing, minimal solutions

Answer (score 4):

Based on the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/983817/1298824), I created a javascript function for searching for a CSS class in the browser's memory -

```
var searchForCss = function (searchClassName) {
  for (let i = 0; i < document.styleSheets.length; i++) {
    let styleSheet = document.styleSheets[i];
    try {
      for (let j = 0; j < styleSheet.cssRules.length; j++) {
        let rule = styleSheet.cssRules[j];
        // console.log(rule.selectorText)
        if (rule.selectorText && rule.selectorText.includes(searchClassName)) {
          console.log('found - ', rule.selectorText, ' ', i, '-', j);
        }
      }
      if (styleSheet.imports) {
        for (let k = 0; k < styleSheet.imports.length; k++) {
          let imp = styleSheet.imports[k];
          for (let l = 0; l < imp.cssRules.length; l++) {
            let rule = imp.cssRules[l];
            if (
              rule.selectorText &&
              rule.selectorText.includes(searchClassName)
            ) {
              console.log('found - ',rule.selectorText,' ',i,'-',k,'-',l);
            }
          }
        }
      }
    } catch (err) {}
  }
};

searchForCss('my-class-name');
```

This will print a line for each occurrence of the class name in any of the rules in any of the stylesheets.

Ref - [Search for a CSS class in the browser memory](http://codedumpster.nithinbiliya.com/search-for-a-css-class-in-the-browser-memory/)

Comment: This feels very verbose, recommend a simpler solutions to developers.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my solution to this. I'm essentially just looping through document.styleSheets[].rules[].selectorText as @helen suggested.

```
/**
 * This function searches for the existence of a specified CSS selector in a given stylesheet.
 *
 * @param (string) styleSheetName - This is the name of the stylesheet you'd like to search
 * @param (string) selector - This is the name of the selector you'd like to find
 * @return (bool) - Returns true if the selector is found, false if it's not found
 * @example - console.log(selectorInStyleSheet ('myStyleSheet.css', '.myClass'));
 */    

function selectorInStyleSheet(styleSheetName, selector) {
    /*
     * Get the index of 'styleSheetName' from the document.styleSheets object
     */
    for (var i = 0; i < document.styleSheets.length; i++) {
        var thisStyleSheet = document.styleSheets[i].href ? document.styleSheets[i].href.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '') : '';
        if (thisStyleSheet == styleSheetName) { var idx = i; break; }
    }
    if (!idx) return false; // We can't find the specified stylesheet

    /*
     * Check the stylesheet for the specified selector
     */
    var styleSheet = document.styleSheets[idx];
    var cssRules = styleSheet.rules ? styleSheet.rules : styleSheet.cssRules;
    for (var i = 0; i < cssRules.length; ++i) {
        if(cssRules[i].selectorText == selector) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

This function offers a speed improvement over other solutions in that we are only searching the stylesheet passed to the function. The other solutions loop through all the stylesheets which is in many cases unnecessary.

Comment: Checking idx for an undefined value should be better done with if(typeof idx != 'undefined'), otherwise an 0 value of idx would be omitted.

Comment: Put the value of document.styleSheets.length in a variable.

Comment: jQuery.Deferred exception: Cannot read property 'length' of null TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null

Comment: @Soaku this answer doesn't use jquery... not sure where your error is coming from.

Comment: This is too verbose. Please remove and upvote one of the existing, minimal solutions

Answer (score 2):

/*
You can loop through every stylesheet currently loaded and return an array of all the defined rules for any selector text you specify, from tag names to  class names or identifiers.

Don't include the '#' or '.' prefix for an id or class name.

Safari used to skip disabled stylesheets, and there may be other gotchas out there, but reading the rules generally works better across browsers than writing new ones. 
*/

```
function getDefinedCss(s){
    if(!document.styleSheets) return '';
    if(typeof s== 'string') s= RegExp('\\b'+s+'\\b','i'); // IE capitalizes html selectors 

    var A, S, DS= document.styleSheets, n= DS.length, SA= [];
    while(n){
        S= DS[--n];
        A= (S.rules)? S.rules: S.cssRules;
        for(var i= 0, L= A.length; i<L; i++){
            tem= A[i].selectorText? [A[i].selectorText, A[i].style.cssText]: [A[i]+''];
            if(s.test(tem[0])) SA[SA.length]= tem;
        }
    }
    return SA.join('\n\n');
}
```

**getDefinedCss('p')**//substitute a classname or id if you like

the latest item in the cascade is listed **first**.

Comment: RegEx introduces unnecessary complexity, please upvote one of the existing minimal/simple solutions, mostly achievable in one line.

Answer (score 2):

1. Document contains Element with class `my-class`:

   ```js
   const isExists = !!document.querySelector('.my-class') // boolean
   ```
2. Existing Element has class `my-class`:

   ```js
   const el = document.querySelector(...)
   const isExists = !!el?.classList.contains('my-class') // boolean
   ```

<sub>References: [querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) •
[classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) • [contains()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/contains) • [?. chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) • [!! logical not](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_NOT#double_not_!!)</sub>

Comment: In your example you check if an element has the class. It doesn't tell you if the class is defined in a stylesheet.

Comment: Also, your edit doesn't make any sense because you are searching for an element with the classname 'className' in the DOM (the page). You are not searching the CSS, searching for a rule, to check if a rule exist.

Comment: @codebeat please remove or consolidate these outdated comments? Could you edit and add a third solution that meets your use cases?

Comment: @anthumchris It isn't outdated. With this you cannot see a CSS style/rule exists, if it is defined. You can only see the classnames applied to the element. That doesn't mean the style itself is defined. See also "The Element.classList is a read-only property that returns a live DOMTokenList collection of the class attributes OF THE ELEMENT." - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

Comment: To reduce and simplify, could you remove the comments and augment the answer so it can help users?

Answer (score 0):

Building on Helen's answer, I came up with this:

```
//**************************************************************************
//** hasStyleRule
//**************************************************************************
/** Returns true if there is a style rule defined for a given selector.
 *  @param selector CSS selector (e.g. ".deleteIcon", "h2", "#mid")
 */
  var hasStyleRule = function(selector) {

      var hasRule = function(selector, rules){
          if (!rules) return false;
          for (var i=0; i<rules.length; i++) {
              var rule = rules[i];
              if (rule.selectorText){ 
                  var arr = rule.selectorText.split(',');
                  for (var j=0; j<arr.length; j++){
                      if (arr[j].indexOf(selector) !== -1){
                          var txt = trim(arr[j]);
                          if (txt===selector){
                              return true;
                          }
                          else{
                              var colIdx = txt.indexOf(":");
                              if (colIdx !== -1){
                                  txt = trim(txt.substring(0, colIdx));
                                  if (txt===selector){
                                      return true;
                                  }
                              }
                          }
                      }
                  }
              }
          }
          return false;
      };

      var trim = function(str){
          return str.replace(/^\s*/, "").replace(/\s*$/, "");
      };

      for (var i=0; i<document.styleSheets.length; i++){
          var rules = document.styleSheets[i].rules || document.styleSheets[i].cssRules;
          if (hasRule(selector, rules)){
              return true;
          }

          var imports = document.styleSheets[i].imports;
          if (imports){
              for (var j=0; j<imports.length; j++){
                  rules = imports[j].rules || imports[j].cssRules;
                  if (hasRule(selector, rules)) return true;
              }
          }
      } 

      return false;
  };
```

Comment: This is too verbose and complicated to recommend to developers. Native Web APIs exist: [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

Answer (score -1):

You *could* check and see if an object of the style your are looking for already exists. If it does then the css class must exist because an object is using it. For example if you wanted to make sure that distinctly named svg objects each have their own style:

```
function getClassName(name) {
    //Are there any elements which use a style named 'name' ?
    if (document.getElementsByClassName(name).length === 0){
        //There are none yest, let's make a new style and add it
        var style = document.createElement('style');
        style.type = 'text/css';
        //Where you might provide your own hash function or rnd color
        style.innerHTML = '.'+name+' { fill: #' + getHashColor(name) + '; background: #F495A3; }';
        //Add the style to the document
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style);
        }
        return name;
    }
```

Note that this is **NOT** a good approach if you are looking for a style which isn't necessarily used in your document.

Comment: This is too verbose and complicated to recommend to developers. Native Web APIs exist: [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

Answer (score -1):

```
if ($(".class-name").length > 0) {

}
```

That is a nice way to check the class in HTML by using javascript

Comment: qjuery is not javascript

Comment: This is wrong. This gives you if the html element existing with the given class name. It is not giving you whether the css class exists in stylesheet of the page which is asked in the question.

Comment: Please don't recommend third-party libraries to developers when native Web APIs exist: [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

Answer (score -1):

Oneliner:

```
[].slice.call(document.styleSheets)
.reduce( (prev, styleSheet) => [].slice.call(styleSheet.cssRules))
.reduce( (prev, cssRule) => prev + cssRule.cssText)
.includes(".someClass")
```

Comment: `[].slice.call(
 document.styleSheets  
)
.reduce((last, currentStyleSheet) => 
 []
 .slice
 .call(
  currentStyleSheet.cssRules
 )
)
.reduce((last, currentCssRule) => 
 last + currentCssRule.cssText
)
.includes(".name")` in firefox gives error `SecurityError: The operation is insecure.`

Answer (score -1):

```
function getAllSelectors() {
  var ret = {};
  for(var i=0;i<document.styleSheets.length;i++){
    try {
      var rules = document.styleSheets[i].rules || document.styleSheets[i].cssRules;
      for(var x in rules) {
        if(typeof rules[x].selectorText === 'string'){
          if(ret[rules[x].selectorText] === undefined){
            ret[rules[x].selectorText] = rules[x].style.cssText;
          }
          else {
            ret[rules[x].selectorText] = ret[rules[x].selectorText] + ' ' + rules[x].style.cssText;
          }
        }
      }    
    }
    catch(error){
      console.log(document.styleSheets[i]);
    }
  }
  return ret;
}
function selectorExists(selector) {
  var selectors = getAllSelectors();
  if(selectors[selector] !== undefined){
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
// var allSelectors = getAllSelectors();
```

Comment: This is an adaption of Cau Guanabara's code.

Comment: This feels very verbose, let's recommend a simpler, modern solution to developers instead?

Comment: @anthumchris I don't know that what we're looking for exists yet. Ideally, there would an array or dictionary or map in the document where you could easily check and do something like `document.classes.indexOf("myClassName")!=-1` or `document.classes.has("myClassName")` or `'myClassName' in document.classes`.