# How do I find out if a CSS class exists in a StyleSheet?

Tags: jquery, css, class, stylesheet

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can you determine if a css class exists with Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/983586/how-can-you-determine-if-a-css-class-exists-with-javascript)

I have a stylesheet, added to a document, this way:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme.css" id="mainPageTheme" />
```

I need to find out if a certain class exists in the respective file, and if it does, associate it to an existing element.

How can I accomplish this with jQuery?
Thank you!

Comment: Do you have a property in the class to look for?