# Get list of CSS Classes in StyleSheet using javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can you determine if a css class exists with Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/983586/how-can-you-determine-if-a-css-class-exists-with-javascript)

Is there a way to check if there is a class named 'some-class-name' in css?

For example, I have:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .box {
        position: absolute;
        left: 150%;
    }
</style>
```

My intention is to randomly assign a class to a div on certain event:

```
var classList = []; //Need to populate this array
$('#updateClass').on('click', function() {
    $('#resultDiv').attr('class',classList[Math.floor((Math.random()*classList.length)+1)]);
});
```

Is it possible to check by JS/jQuery whether a class named 'box' exists in the stylesheet?

I referred to **[This Question - How can you determine if a css class exists with Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/983586/how-can-you-determine-if-a-css-class-exists-with-javascript)**, But the answer didn't help me **because the link in the answer doesn't exists anymore**.

Thanks.

Comment: check this answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/983586/how-can-you-determine-if-a-css-class-exists-with-javascript

Comment: `if ($('.validation-errors').length){ /*your code here */ }` but i suspect it will check element has class ??

Comment: Is there any reason for you to check for class names in css?

Comment: other question, why you want to do this? whats the reason?

Comment: @silly I read that as whats the "season", the winter bash is getting to me

Comment: Perhaps you should consider using the [data attribute](http://api.jquery.com/data/).

Comment: Exists in the document, or is specified in the stylesheet(s)?

Comment: That question doesn't helped me

Comment: Just because the answer didn't help you doesn't make it less of a duplicate. You need to explain how your question differs from that one. Not the answers.

Comment: Its because, the link in the answer doesn't exists anymore

Comment: I said **question**, not **answer**. You can always place a bounty on the other question if it is similar to what you're looking for; otherwise you need to explain how your question is different from the other one that it should not be closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above ([How can you determine if a css class exists with Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/983586/how-can-you-determine-if-a-css-class-exists-with-javascript)), you could scan the complete CSS for the requested class, or you could add the requested class to an element and check if the attriubtes of the class apply to it. For example:

```
document.getElementById('yourTestElementID').className=newClass;
if(document.getElementById('yourTestElementID').style.position === 'thevalue' ) {
  // class exists....
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Your random algorithm:

```
Math.floor((Math.random()*classList.length)+1)
```

will generate random number from specific range or more generally from 1 to classList.length.

You just need to be sure that the class names that you are going to use and will be populated in the array will exists.