# Use a custom CSS style if some CSS class is not defined

Tags: javascript, css

Is there a way using pure javascript to check if a CSS class is defined, and if it is, then use it, and if not, define a custom style?

Example:

**If CSS class `demo_class` does not exist:**

```
<div style="text-size:12px">Some content here...</div>
```

**Else:**

```
<div class="demo_class">Some content here...</div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can you determine if a css class exists with Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/983586/how-can-you-determine-if-a-css-class-exists-with-javascript)

Answer (score -1):

Forst you need to select that element, for example give it some id

```
<div id="some-id">Some content here...</div>
```

js:

```
var element=document.getElementById('some-id');
```

Now you can check its class and set style

```
if(element.class!='demo_class')
{
  element.style.fontSize='12px';
}
```

Comment: I think he wants to check if the classname is defined in the css (not if the element has the class)

Answer (score -1):

You can do this:

```
if(typeof $('#some-id').attr('class') != 'undefined'){
    if($('#some-id').attr('class').indexOf('demo_class') > -1) {
        //Exist the class in the div
    } else {
        //Not exist the class in the div
        $('#some-id').addClass('demo_class');
    }
} else {
    $('#some-id').addClass('demo_class');
}
```